# How to stop emacs minimap from horizontal recentering?

Tags: emacs

I installed the minimap package from elpa. (20150108 version).

I find it a little annoying that each time I move cursor to the end of one line, especially for the long lines, the minimap will recenter horizontally to the right side.

In such case I lose the visual of the left side of document, which is helpful in locating codes.

Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimap package has two options for configuring centering:

`minimap-always-recenter` and `minimap-recenter-type`

I think you want: `(setq minimap-recenter-type 'free)`

but you should [check the source out](https://github.com/dustinlacewell/emacs-minimap/blob/master/minimap.el#L132) for other possibilities.